# Cant make AT Master application to work on NUCLEO-LRWAN1/NUCLEO-L073RZ pair

Tags: lorawan

I have P-NUCLEO-LRWAN2 starter pack and I'm trying to run AT Master application on NUCLEO-LRWAN1/NUCLEO-L073RZ pair with supplied in I-CUBE-LRWAN Expansion Package. It looks like all fine (i.e firmware compiled and loaded onto NUCLEO-L073RZ without any problem). But GW cant get any data from the Sensor Device. Finally, when I checked with SDR , I cant see any Tx activity from the Sensor device .. I will be so happy if you can make comment on this. many thanks in advance, reha

Comment: Please add a complete example of what you are doing. We can't know what you did wrong if you don't tell us the AT commands (and responses to them) you are doing

Comment: Hi Tarick,
thank you for your answer..
Environment: STM P-NUCLEO-LRWAN2 Starter pack for LORAWAN tests. 
- a LORAWAN GW , STM NUCLEO-F746ZG development board and LRWAN_GS_HF1 extension board. which is working perfectly
- a LORAWAN End Node, NUCLEO-L073RZ development board and I-NUCLEO-LRWAN1 LoRa® HF band expansion board.

Problem definition:
For End Node,  Im trying to use AT Master application  which is  supplied in I-CUBE-LRWAN Expansion Package. I uploaded Firmware (i.e firmware compiled and loaded onto NUCLEO-L073RZ without any problem). But End Node doesnt send any package. thanks

Comment: Great to know the hardware but what are the steps you are actually taking? Which AT commands do you issue? Do you do a OTAA or ABP join? What SF are you using? Is it CNF or UNCF?

Comment: Hi again.. 
NUCLEO-LRWAN1/NUCLEO-L073RZ pair  should start SENDING sensor data when you compile and upload AT Master application which is supplied in I-CUBE-LRWAN Expansion Package. Sadly, it is not sending any data.. Currently, device is not sending and package, verified by SDR .. So, this problem not related with LORAWAN protocol , so join mechanism, SF etc not relevant in this moment.

Answer (score 0):

You are misunderstanding what the software is supposed to do. The AT Master Application creates an interactive ([AT command style](https://www.st.com/resource/en/application_note/dm00346311-examples-of-at-commands-on-icubelrwan-stmicroelectronics.pdf)) application which can be used to connect as a LoRaWAN modem.

The End-Node application is an independent, autonomous node that will send it's own messages. This is the code that can be modified to transmit your messages on it's own.